# Count custom values from a list in a python dataframe per column

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list:

```
x = ['hi', 'hello', '-', '01.01.9999']
```

And I have a DataFrame with a lot of columns. I want to loop over all columns and count the occurrences of my custom list.

As a result, I want something like this:

```
column_1, 'hi', 23
column_1, 'hello', 3
column_1, '-', 5
column_1, '01.01.9999', 0
...
column_n, 'hi', 0
column_n, 'hello', 35
column_n, '-', 15
column_n, '01.01.9999', 54
```

Already have this:

```
user_selected_features['dummy_key_words'] = ['hi', 'hello', '-', '01.01.9999']
```

```
for x in user_selected_features['dummy_key_words']:
    for column in _tmp_df:
```

I tried a lot of things in the loop, but nothing seems to return the correct result.

```
count = _tmp_df[_tmp_df[column] == x].count()
count = _tmp_df[column].str.count(x)
count = [_tmp_df[column] == x].count
```

How can I count the occurrence of a custom value per column in a DataFrame?

Comment: How is the original dataframe?

Comment: Can you include samples of `user_selected_features` and `_tmp_df`?

Comment: Just a "standard" dataframe with headers, columns and different data in it

Comment: Hi @not_speshal, the user selected features is the x list at the start for example

Comment: In one cell, can you have the value `"- hi hello 01.01.9999"`?

Comment: technically possible, but wont happen in productive data @Corralien

Comment: So, one cell contains one of your words or not, that's all?

Comment: exactly @Corralien. I am looking for "dummy data" in my data

Comment: does you df contains these exact values of x or these values are part of string?

Comment: exact value @AnuragDabas

Comment: Can you check is [this works for you](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68848599/16343464)? Processing should be quite fast. I proposed two formats for output: table and long.

Comment: will do @mozway, just testing all answers right now., takes some time. thanks!

Comment: Thank you all, @AnuragDabas answer looked the most easy and straight forward solution to me

Comment: also works very well @mozway!

Comment: Of note, while @AnuragDabas answer is very nice, it will become slower when the number of columns increase due to the loop (list comprehension). For example our two solutions are equally fast on 5 columns, but mine it ~7 times faster for 500 columns. Not to say that you should not use it, but just make sure to compare the possibilities in the real use case. It is possible that there is no ideal solution depending on the use case.

Comment: Thats a very good point @mozway. Probably will change to your solution in near future. I appreciate your time. Thank you!

Comment: @mozway no offence and sorry if  I was wrong but have you tested it?...I mean that you are saying that it is 7*faster then list comprehension...because I tested (30000 rows*600 columns) it in curiosity and didn't found anything like that but find the opposite case ...I found that list comprehension 5-6 times faster

Comment: @AnuragDabas no offense taken ;) Yes I have tested on `x = ['hi', 'hello', '-', '01.01.9999'];import string;np.random.seed(0);df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.choice(x+list(string.ascii_letters), size=100000).reshape(-1, 500),columns=[chr(i) for i in range(500)])`. But as I said, it's possible one answer is better in one case and not in another one. This was the only point of my comment. Your answer is perfectly fine!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yet another way by `concat()`+list comprehension which you can try:

```
out=pd.concat([df.loc[df[y].isin(x),y].value_counts() for y in df],axis=1)
```

OR

without passing axis parameter in `concat()`:

```
out=pd.concat([df.loc[df[y].isin(x),y].value_counts() for y in df]).reset_index()
```

Comment: Works like a charm, with one exception. It doesnt return values if the keyword is a number and the pandas column is "int64". Any idea..? Thank you for your help! edit: nevermind, works with applymap(str)

Comment: @JohnDole sir I tested it and it is working if you have int64 column and an integer value in x...sir can you pls recheck **:)**

Answer (score 1):

I do not have a `DataFrame` as an example, but you can try this :

```py
>>> df[df['text'].isin(x)]
...     .groupby('text', as_index=False)['value']
...     .sum()
...     .sort_values('value', ascending=False)
```

Answer (score 1):

You can compute the value counts for a single columns as follows:

```
df['col1'].value_counts()
```

To count the values for all columns, you can do the following:

```
df.apply(pd.Series.value_counts).fillna(0)
```

This will give you a dataframe with the values as index, the column names the same as the original column names, and the values the number of occurences in the original dataframe.

You can get the counts per column for specific values by selecting only those rows from the resulting dataframe.

As an example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame(
    {
        "col1": ["a", "b", 1, "a"],
        "col2": ["a", "a", "c", "c"],
        "col3": ["a", 1, 1, "d"],
    }
)

counts = df.apply(pd.Series.value_counts).fillna(0)
counts.loc[["a", 1]]
```

Will give:

```
    col1    col2    col3
"a" 2.0     2.0     1.0
1   1.0     0.0     2.0
```

Comment: I am looking for a value counts for specific words, not for the values in the DataFrame itself

Comment: @JohnDole Does the example I added solve your problem?

Comment: Hi @Swier, I tried your code. It looks like it works, with 2 exceptions: The NA are not  filled and it looks like it only works for STRINGS, not for numbers. Do you have an idea? Appreciate your help, thank you very much!

Comment: @JohnDole It should work with numbers as well (see updated example), and I can't tell why it doesn't fill in the NaNs without your code.

Answer (score 1):

A very simple suggestion, given a df:

```
import pandas as pd
data = pd.DataFrame({'Col_1':['hi','hello'],'Col_2':['-','not_imp']})
keywords_check=['hi','hello','-']

'   Col_1    Col_2
0     hi        -
1  hello    not_imp'
```

You can loop and use value_counts:

```
list_values=[]
for col in data.columns:
    col_count = data[col].value_counts().to_frame()
    list_values.append(col_count)
```

And then:

```
pd.concat(list_values).T[keywords_check]
```

Returns a column per word and count per row

```
'        hi  hello    -
  Col_1  1.0    1.0  NaN
  Col_2  NaN    NaN  1.0'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with `apply` and `value_counts` to get the counts. Then use `stack()` and `swaplevel()` to match your required output format.

###### Code:

```
counter = df.apply(pd.value_counts).reindex(x).fillna(0)
output = counter.astype(int).stack().swaplevel()
```

###### Example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"column_1": ["hi", "hello", "hello", "bye", "nothing", "01.01.9999"],
                   "column_2": ["hi", "hi", "hi", "-", "-", "nothing"],
                   "column_3": ["hi", "hi", "hello", "-", "-", "nothing"]
                   })
x = ['hi', 'hello', '-', '01.01.9999']
counter = df.apply(pd.value_counts).reindex(x).fillna(0)
output = counter.astype(int).stack().swaplevel()

>>> output
column_1  hi            1
column_2  hi            3
column_3  hi            2
column_1  hello         2
column_2  hello         0
column_3  hello         1
column_1  -             0
column_2  -             2
column_3  -             2
column_1  01.01.9999    1
column_2  01.01.9999    0
column_3  01.01.9999    0
dtype: int32
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
# Sample
>>> df

    A           B      C
0  hi       hello   word
1  in  01.01.9999  maybe

# Create a multiindex to have all possible combinations at the end
mi = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df.columns, x], names=['column', 'word'])

# Output
>>> df.apply(lambda w: w[w.isin(x)].value_counts()) \
      .rename_axis(index='word', columns='column') \
      .unstack().rename('count').dropna().astype(int) \
      .reindex(mi, fill_value=0).reset_index()

   column        word  count
0       A          hi      1
1       A       hello      0
2       A           -      0
3       A  01.01.9999      0
4       B          hi      0
5       B       hello      1
6       B           -      0
7       B  01.01.9999      1
8       C          hi      0
9       C       hello      0
10      C           -      0
11      C  01.01.9999      0
```

Answer (score 1):

**Try:**

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.DataFrame({'strings': ['hi', 'hello', '-', '01.01.9999', 'hi', np.nan, '01.01.9999', 'hi'],\
                   'stringsToo': ['hi', np.nan, '-', '01.01.9999', 'hello', '-', '01.01.9999', 'hi']})

x = ['hi', 'hello', '-', '01.01.9999']

ss = []

for i, col in enumerate(df.columns):
    s = df[col].str.get_dummies().reindex(columns=x).sum()
    s = s.rename(col)
    ss.append(s)
    
df_counts = pd.concat(ss, axis=1, keys=[s.name for s in ss])


print(df, '\n')
print(df_counts)

      strings  stringsToo
0          hi          hi
1       hello         NaN
2           -           -
3  01.01.9999  01.01.9999
4          hi       hello
5         NaN           -
6  01.01.9999  01.01.9999
7          hi          hi 

            strings  stringsToo
hi                3           2
hello             1           1
-                 1           2
01.01.9999        2           2
```

Answer (score 1):

I am surprised no one proposed a simple answer using stack/unstack:

```
x = ['hi', 'hello', '-', '01.01.9999']
(df.stack()
   .groupby(level=1).value_counts()
   .unstack(level=0, fill_value=0).loc[x]
)
```

output:

```
            column_1  column_2  column_3
hi                 1         3         2
hello              2         0         1
-                  0         2         2
01.01.9999         1         0         0
```

input:

```
     column_1 column_2 column_3
0          hi       hi       hi
1       hello       hi       hi
2       hello       hi    hello
3         bye        -        -
4     nothing        -        -
5  01.01.9999  nothing  nothing
```

#### keep as long format:

```
(df.stack()
   .groupby(level=1).value_counts()
   .loc(axis=0)[pd.IndexSlice[:, x]]
)
```

output:

```
column_1  hi            1
column_2  hi            3
column_3  hi            2
column_1  hello         2
column_3  hello         1
column_2  -             2
column_3  -             2
column_1  01.01.9999    1
```